# Firebase sendPasswordResetEmail never completes

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to send a password reset email with firebase but it doesn't work. It doesn't throw any exceptions either. It just never completes, and I see no errors in the console. I tried debugging it and I saw that the parameter action code is null, is it supposed to be? All guides covering this don't add any action codesettings. I've tried signing out the user first but that doesn't seem to work. What to do?

This `await firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: currentEmail);` is nested in a try-catch block that's all.

Console output:

```
W/System  (  757): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I/System.out(  757): isEmailSend:POST
I/System.out(  757): port:443
D/GraphicBuffer(  757): register, handle(0x8240d540) (w:720 h:1504 s:720 f:0x1 u:f02)
I/System.out(  757): Check isMmsSendPdu
I/System.out(  757): [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
```

This is all I see. The future just never completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly i was stuck too in this while doing my first attempt.I realized i didn't activated resetpassword method on firebase console authetication.
After this i got same result because while trying with email doesn't exist on firebase console user panel that mail adress.
My suggestion check turn on password reset method on console and try it with exist email user. and be sure you don't try with null in email
all of that if doesn't work maybe it can be about the port settings.
And one more try change this

```
firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: currentEmail)
```

to

```
firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(currentEmail)
```

Comment: Can't find that method to enable, where is it?

Comment: I'll try with an existing email too, to verify.

Comment: authentication ->templates resetpassword check there also be sure email-password sign in method turn on. if it's like that it must be send e-mail from your app owner email. And check you should have defined support email on project settings. and i updated my reply maybe while getting e-mail adress from user there is a problem you can write currentEmail on terminal to check it or try give there spesific e-mail adress manually

Comment: Trying it with an existing email address worked thanks. It seems no Exceptions are thrown from FirebaseAuth when any of the required parameters are null or empty. You have to attach a then() part to the future to see those types of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your emulator is connected to the internet. Sometimes the wifi is on but does not connected to the internet.

and also make sure you email/password sign-in method on firebase is enabled
[image]

and if that doesn't work then add this line: `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to your android > app > src > main > AndroidMaifest.xml

Comment: I'm not using an emulator though I understand that the issue usually comes from that. I have a real device

Comment: i have add another solution to the first one